# How to generate a bubble chart of a directed graph with several properties using Manipulate[.]

Tags: graphs-and-networks, manipulate, code-request, charts

This code:

```
ClearAll[wam, vLabels, sa, wag, cs, evc, cause, effect, chartData];

(* convert the matrix into a directed graph *)
wam = {{0, 0.03, 0, 0.03, 0.02, 0.04, 0.02, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03,
     0.01, 0.02, 0.02}, {0.05, 0, 0.07, 0, 0, 0, 0.03, 0.03, 0, 0.01, 
    0.06, 0.04, 0.01, 0.04, 0.04}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.06, 
    0, 0, 0.07, 0, 0}, {0.05, 0, 0.03, 0, 0.04, 0.05, 0.03, 0.02, 0, 
    0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03}, {0.06, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.05, 
    0.04, 0.06, 0.03, 0.08, 0.06, 0.05, 0.03, 0.07, 0.06}, {0.01, 
    0.02, 0.07, 0.03, 0.06, 0, 0.02, 0.01, 0.06, 0.01, 0.09, 0.05, 
    0.07, 0.02, 0.03}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.02, 0.06, 0.06, 
    0.01, 0, 0}, {0, 0.05, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.05, 0.09, 0, 0.06, 
    0.01, 0.02, 0.07, 0, 0.15, 0.02}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.07, 0, 0, 0.04, 0, 0}, {0.01, 0.07, 0.03, 0.04, 0, 0.04, 0.05, 
    0.08, 0.06, 0, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01, 0.03, 0.09}, {0.04, 0.07, 0.05, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.03, 0, 0}, {0, 0.01, 0.06, 0, 0.01, 
    0.07, 0.009`, 0.006`, 0.007`, 0.012`, 0.008`, 0, 0, 0.011`, 
    0.01`}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.01, 0, 0.06, 
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
vLabels = {1->AGF, 2->CO12, 3->MA1, 4->MA2, 5->EGW, 6->CST, 7->WHS, 8->HOT, 9->TSC, 10->FIN, 11->EST, 12->ADM, 13->EDU, 14->HLT, 15->ENT};
vnames = {"AGF","CO12","MA1","MA2","EGW","CST","WHS","HOT","TSC","FIN","EST","ADM","EDU","HLT","ENT"};
sa = SparseArray[wam];
wag = Graph[sa["NonzeroPositions"], EdgeWeight -> sa["NonzeroValues"],
    DirectedEdges -> True, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"];

(* compute some statistics *)
evc = EigenvectorCentrality[wag] /. vLabels;
cs = FindGraphCommunities[wag] /. vLabels;
nghEdges = EdgeList[ NeighborhoodGraph[wag, 4]] /. vLabels;

(* Bubble chart *)
cause = Total[wam, {2}];
effect = Total@wam;
chartData = Transpose@{cause, effect, evc};

BubbleChart[
 <|Thread[vnames -> chartData]|>,
 ChartLabels -> Automatic,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Cause", Bold], Style["Effect", Bold]},
 RotateLabel -> True,
 ImageSize -> 300
 ]
```

produces:

[image]

I want to further extend this bubble chart by adding 4 pieces of information:

1. Assign the same color for community members in each community;
2. Show directed edges from a given vertex `V1` by using `NeighborhoodGraph[g,V1]`;
3. The final `Manipulate[.]` code should allow for a selection of `NeighborhoodGraph[.]` vertex `V1` using `ControlType -> Setter` for vertices.
4. Finally, `PlotLabels` should be added to the bubble chart to identify each community (with different colors) and the definition of the directed linkages from/to the selected vertex `V1`.

`Manipulate[...]` be of the form so that once an input matrix is given, the bubble chart described above should be generated.

The above code shows what I could do so far.

**EDIT**

With the code by @Bob Hanlon, the bubble chart is generated by:

```
BubbleChart[
 Association /@ 
  GatherBy[Normal[<|Thread[vnames -> chartData]|>], 
   Position[cs, ToExpression[#[[1]]]][[1, 1]] &],
 ChartLabels -> Automatic,
 ChartStyle -> "Pastel",
 ChartLegends->Placed[{"comm 1","comm 2","comm 3","comm 4"}, Below],
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold] & /@ {"Cause", "Effect"}),
 PlotTheme -> "Business",
 PlotLabel->"Sector dominance, centrality, communities and neighborhood graph",    
 ImagePadding->{{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Scaled[.01]}},
 ImageSize -> 375
 ]
```

[image]

I still need to map `NeighborhoodGraph[wag, 4]`, for example, on top of the bubble chart by keeping the coordinates of vertices unchanged. Experiments with each vertex should be done by `Manipulate[...]`.

Comment: The code does not produce the shown chart. `vnames` is not defined.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon: Sorry for my mistake. Please see the edition in the question.

Comment: To color the bubbles use `BubbleChart[Association /@ GatherBy[Normal[<|Thread[vnames -> chartData]|>], Position[cs, ToExpression[#[[1]]]][[1, 1]] &], ChartLabels -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold] & /@ {"Cause", "Effect"}), ImageSize -> 300]` I don't understand the rest of the question.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon: The rest of the question is all about plotting the edges in a `NeighborhoodGraph[wag, 4]` on to the bubble chart by keeping the positions of vertices in the bubble chart fixed. Using `Manipulate` would be preferable to  repeat the same plotting for each one of the vertices in the bubble chart.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon: I also corrected the mistake in the question that was written as `Manipulate[matrix_]:=`. Obviously this is not possible because `Manipulate` is a built-in code. I meant to use `Manipulate[...]` to perform an automated generation of a bubble chart for each vertex.

Comment: @TugrulTemel NeighborhoodGraph[wag, 4] gave almost full graph since graph is almost complete graph.  Do you want to just edge coming to vertex or out?

Comment: @halmir: In fact, I was initially thinking of using `VertexIn` and `VertexOut` in `Manipulate[.]`. That will be much more useful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct a weighted graph:

```
wag = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[vnames, wam, 0, 
  EdgeLabels -> 
   Placed["EdgeWeight", Automatic, NumberForm[#, {Infinity, 2}] &]];

evc = EigenvectorCentrality[wag];
cs = FindGraphCommunities[wag];
```

I modified evc to show 0 size vertex in BubbleChart:

```
cause = Total[wam, {2}];
effect = Total@wam;
chartData = Transpose@{cause, effect, evc /. {0. -> .001}};

bubble = 
 BubbleChart[
  Association /@ 
    Map[Style[#[[1]], Bold, 
        Rescale[#[[2, 3]], 
         MinMax[chartData[[All, 3]]], {7, 15}] ] -> #[[2]] &, 
     GatherBy[Normal[<|Thread[vnames -> chartData]|>], 
      Position[cs, #[[1]]][[1, 1]] &], {2}], 
  ChartLabels -> Callout[Automatic], ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
  ChartLegends -> 
   Placed[{"comm 1", "comm 2", "comm 3", "comm 4"}, Below], 
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold] & /@ {"Cause", "Effect"}), 
  PlotTheme -> "Business", 
  PlotLabel -> 
   "Sector dominance, centrality, communities and in-out edges", 
  ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Scaled[.01]}}, 
  ImageSize -> 375]
```

Extract disks inside the chart to use for vertex sizes in a graph:

```
disk = Cases[bubble, _Disk, Infinity];
vsize = Rule @@@ (disk /. 
     Thread[Sort[disk[[All, 1]]] -> 
       VertexList[wag][[Ordering[chartData[[All, ;; 2]]]]]]);
```

Create a new graph with new options:

```
ngraph = 
  Graph[wag, VertexCoordinates -> chartData[[All, ;; 2]], 
   VertexSize -> vsize, VertexShapeFunction -> None, 
   EdgeStyle -> 
    Directive[Thickness[.01], Arrowheads[.04], GrayLevel[.5, .5]], 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
```

Final manipulator:

```
Manipulate[
 Block[{es}, 
  es = Switch[edges, "Out", 
    If[# =!= {}, Style[#, Blue], #] &@
     EdgeList[ngraph, vertex \[DirectedEdge] _], "In", 
    If[# =!= {}, Style[#, Pink], #] &@
     EdgeList[ngraph, _ \[DirectedEdge] vertex], "Both", 
    List[If[# =!= {}, Style[#, Blue], #] &@
      EdgeList[ngraph, vertex \[DirectedEdge] _], 
     If[# =!= {}, Style[#, Pink], #] &@
      EdgeList[ngraph, _ \[DirectedEdge] vertex]], _, {}];
  Show[{bubble, 
    If[es === None || Length[es] == 0, {}, 
     HighlightGraph[ngraph, es, 
      GraphHighlightStyle -> "DehighlightHide"]]}]], {edges, {None, 
   "In", "Out", "Both"}}, {vertex, VertexList[ngraph]}, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: This is excellent!!! It is very appealing, especially the presentation of the arrows. How can I adjust the size of vertex names on the graph? They look disproportional. Many thanks for your effort.

Comment: Can you also add "Both" as a control to see both in and out links of a chosen sector? This will complete the full picture of the sector degree.

Comment: @TugrulTemel edited

Comment: I have two more adjustments to make in `Manipulate[.]`. (1) give different colors to `In` (Pink) and `Out` (Blue). (2) take only 2 digits for edge weights (in my original problem edge weights have 6 digits). If `EdgeWeight < 0.001`, then assign it `0.00` but keep the associated edge on the graph. These questions concern the esthetics of the figure, and hence, you may just ignore them if it is too much. Thank you again.

Comment: @TugrulTemel EdgeWeight already shows only two digit. Do you mean modify original matrix?

Comment: Yes, currently the edge weights are two digits because I wanted to keep the example simple. In the original matrix, I have numbers with 6 digits and I only want to see two digits in the graph. If a number is of the form `0.0000034`, then I like to see it as `0` knowing that it is a small number. I do not want to modify the matrix given in the example, but I want to apply this code to different matrices with more digits.

Comment: @TugrulTemel updated

Comment: Really, thank you so much for your time and for this beautiful graph. It works like a charm!!! With your permission, I like to put it as an MMA `Demonstration` because it is a very useful graph for those in network analysis. The graph captures dominance, centrality, community, and degree information of a network at one go.

Comment: @TugrulTemel no problem

Comment: Thanks for the permission. I will link the demonstration to "Share Link" in the question so that people's contributions are known. Thanks again for this.

Comment: I have a question about the code above. We have `Association /@ 
    Map[Style[#[[1]], Bold, 
        Rescale[#[[2, 3]], 
         MinMax[chartData[[All, 3]]], {7, 15}] ] -> #[[2]] &, 
     GatherBy[Normal[<|Thread[vnames -> chartData]|>], 
      Position[cs, #[[1]]][[1, 1]] &], {2}]` and I really do not understand it. We rescale `eigenvector centrality-bubble size` but I do not understand why we rescale it in the interval `{7,15}`. Given like, `Rescale[#[[2,3]], {7,15}]`. This creates a problem in some cases with different graph size.

Comment: @TugrulTemel that's for rescaling text size.  You can modify whatever value you want.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Somehow the code with different sizes of nodes are giving errors in the stage of rescaling. Therefore, I was thinking that maybe that is the source of the error, but apparently, not. For some adjacency matrices, I have trouble in that stage. What can it be? I will send you the error statement in next comment.

Comment: Here is the error that comes up after running `disk` and `vsize`. `Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {{0.0051112,0.0820899},{0.00970665,0.115901},{0.0104162,0.079424},{0.0104162,0.079424},{0.010595,0.0909953},{0.010595,0.0909953},{0.0148872,0.0842114},{0.0148872,0.0842114},{0.0151271,0.0775509},{0.0176683,0.0922383},<<27>>}->{se85,mi31,mi17,mi23,st61,sb69,me35,mi10,sp58,mi28,<<23>>} cannot be combined.`

Comment: In my new example, `VertexList[wag] // Length` and `chartData[[All, ;; 2]] // Length` both have 33 elements but somehow `disk = Cases[aBubble, _Disk, Infinity] // Length` gives 37 elements. I think this is the problem. Why does this happen?

Comment: If I use `Association /@ 
 GatherBy[Normal[<|Thread[verList -> chartData]|>], 
  Position[cs, #[[1]]][[1, 1]] &]` instead of the `bubble` given in the above code, everything works fine.